# How can I surround dt dd tags without using div?

Tags: html, css

How I can get the same result of the following code without using div as direct child of dl ?

```css
dl{
    padding: 0;margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

dl div{
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
  margin-right:2%;
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

dl dt{
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

dd{
  margin:0;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
    <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa. Nunc commodo, quam et commodo gravida, nisi risus vehicula tortor.
    </dd>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
    <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa.
    </dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Note : I use here as example just two dt and their dd surrounded by div, in reality i need more than two ...

### **Edited 2020-01-04**

Today using **div** inside **dl** is valid practice ["Divs are valid elements inside of a Description List"](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/divs-are-valid-elements-inside-of-a-definition-list/).

Comment: You can use `span`. If you want it be block level element set it to `display:block`

Comment: @abhishekkannojia using span is a semantic error. Span is for inline content so you should use it to wrap small portion of your text or images.

Comment: @Ema.jar FYI: `<span>` is a non-semantic wrapper which its default computed value of `display` is `inline`. There's nothing wrong with altering the `display` to `block`. Though in this case, it would be totally invalid HTML.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia ... as div span not allowed as child of dl

Comment: if you don't care about html validation you can use whatever tag you like. But it is wrong. actually you can not use any tags inside `<dl>` except `<dt>` followd by `<dd>`! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: Considering the layout that you want to achieve, this content will not work well if you want the HTML to be valid.   I would change the `dl` to something like `section` (or some other block level element) and then the inner `div` could be `article` and then the `dt` could be `h3` and then `dd` could be `p`.  There are many ways of doing this.

Comment: @MarcAudet using dl in this case(my case) is perfect, but if there no simple and clear css solution then I will work with your opinion

Answer (score 4):

You could use CSS Columns:

```
dl { -webkit-columns: 2; -moz-columns: 2; columns: 2; }
```

Avoid column break inside the elements `dt` and `dd`:

```
dt, dd { 
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;  
}
```

Avoid column break just after the `dt`:

```
dt { 
    -webkit-column-break-after: avoid; 
    column-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    break-after: avoid-column;      
}
```

**Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9o797s77/**

**Example Snippet:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
dl {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 8px;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
}
dt {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-column-break-after: avoid;
  column-break-after: avoid;
  page-break-after: avoid;
  break-after: avoid-column;
}
dd {
  text-align: justify;
}
dt,
dd {
  margin: 8px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
  <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa. Nunc commodo, quam et commodo gravida, nisi risus vehicula tortor.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
  <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
  <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
  <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa.
  </dd>
</dl>
```

**Edit**: Added FireFox specific vendor-prefix. Checked with IE11, Edge, Chrome 47, and Firefox 41.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer, but when I run the snippet, I see one column, not two.  Something is not quite right.  I am using Firefox.  However, your code does work as expected in Chrome and MS Edge.

Comment: me too, it doesn't work for me and also it seems that it work just in new browsers ...

Comment: Damn FF. There fixed. Added the vendor prefix. Thank you so much  @MarcAudet for pointing that out.

Comment: @BBeta: Yes. Modern browsers (For IE > 9).

Comment: Thanks @MarcAudet for the snippet edit. Missed that... occupied in something else alongside.

Answer (score 2):

How about wrap with `<dl>` and finish?

```css
dl{
    padding: 0;margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:2%;
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

dl dt{
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

dd{
  margin:0;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
    <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa. Nunc commodo, quam et commodo gravida, nisi risus vehicula tortor.
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
    <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa.
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `div` solution as it is in the OP. It's now valid HTML, see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-dl-element

> ### The dl element
>
> #### Content model:
>
> Either: Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more `dt` elements followed by one or more `dd` elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.
>
> Or: One or more `div` elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.

```html
<dl>
 <div>
  <dt> Last modified time </dt>
  <dd> 2004-12-23T23:33Z </dd>
 </div>
 <div>
  <dt> Recommended update interval </dt>
  <dd> 60s </dd>
 </div>
 <div>
  <dt> Authors </dt>
  <dt> Editors </dt>
  <dd> Robert Rothman </dd>
  <dd> Daniel Jackson </dd>
 </div>
</dl>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your page to be responsive its better to use a div, or else you can directly change the same code by removing div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<dl>
  
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
    <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa. Nunc commodo, quam et commodo gravida, nisi risus vehicula tortor.
    </dd>
  
  
  
    <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor</dt>
    <dd>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget dui accumsan, dapibus lacus sed, auctor massa.
    </dd>
  
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use span, which wont change the design, but span only user for small chunks of code inside it.

**Difference:** The difference between span and div is that a span element is in-line and usually used for a small chunk of HTML inside a line (such as inside a paragraph) whereas a div (division) element is block-line (which is basically equivalent to having a line-break before and after it) and used to group larger chunks of code.